# PHP Array Conversion with removing Array Name

Tags: php

Hello i want to remove "news_list" from php json array.

```
{
    "news_list": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "group_id": 1,
            "news_title": "fbb",
            "news_description": "gfhgfh",
            "status": "Y",
            "created_at": "2017-05-11 16:04:26",
            "updated_at": "2017-05-11 16:04:26"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "group_id": 1,
            "news_title": "ewrdf",
            "news_description": "dsfsdfdsfsdffffffffffffff",
            "status": "Y",
            "created_at": "2017-05-12 10:59:01",
            "updated_at": "2017-05-12 10:59:01"
        }
    ]
}
```

Desired Output :

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "group_id": 1,
        "news_title": "fbb",
        "news_description": "gfhgfh",
        "status": "Y",
        "created_at": "2017-05-11 16:04:26",
        "updated_at": "2017-05-11 16:04:26"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "group_id": 1,
        "news_title": "ewrdf",
        "news_description": "dsfsdfdsfsdffffffffffffff",
        "status": "Y",
        "created_at": "2017-05-12 10:59:01",
        "updated_at": "2017-05-12 10:59:01"
    }
]
```

is there ant in-built PHP function for same ?.if there i s any in built function then please convey me.

Comment: `$new_array = $old_array['news_list']` try something like this.

Comment: Hello @Akam, it throws illegal offset error

Comment: try `$new_array = $old_array->news_list`

Comment: @BenLonsdale. Not working

Comment: there is nothing like direct function to fetch any key data of json. You need to convert your json to array or object using `json_decode` and then can perform or fetch what you looking for.

Comment: Thanks @Naincy for formatting question.

Comment: @SwapnilW, can you add your brief php code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing like direct function to fetch any key data of json. You need to convert your json to array or object using `json_decode` and then can perform or fetch what you looking for.

```
$res = json_decode($data);   // return object
print_r($res->news_list);
```

Or

```
$res = json_decode($data, true);   // return array
print_r($res['news_list']);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
$oldDataArray = json_decode('{"news_list":[{"id":2,"group_id":1,"news_title":"fbb","news_description":"gfhgfh","status":"Y","created_at":"2017-05-11 16:04:26","updated_at":"2017-05-11 16:04:26"},{"id":3,"group_id":1,"news_title":"ewrdf","news_description":"dsfsdfdsfsdffffffffffffff","status":"Y","created_at":"2017-05-12 10:59:01","updated_at":"2017-05-12 10:59:01"}]}');

$newDataArray = $oldDataArray->news_list;

echo '<pre>';
print_r($newDataArray);
echo '</pre>';
```